# Powershell console does not load

Tags: powershell

The PowerShell console isn't loading.

I'm using Sitecore 10.1.3 on managed cloud.

How can I troubleshoot this.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi @sukesh. Make sure to do some searching before asking a question. For your next question, please provide more information and also include warning/error messages directly as text.

Comment: @sukesh Did you check Sitecore Logs? Are there any errors pertaining to the same?